# Which servlet api gets/sets objects in request and application scope?

Tags: java, servlets

I am a bit unclear, it seems request.getAttribute (or setAttribute) is for application scope i.e. shared accross all servlets in the application.

Is there something that I can get/set on a per request (not session, but per web request) scope?

Example, in a filter, I may want to add something for this request only that I get then retrieve in my servlet's doGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *it seems request.getAttribute (or setAttribute) is for application scope i.e. shared accross all servlets in the application.*

This is not true. This is only applicable to those methods on [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). You're apparently mixing it with [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) or misinterpreting the concrete problem you're currently facing, but didn't tell anything about in your question. The `HttpServletRequest` instance and all of its attributes is definitely request scoped.

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909)

Answer (score 0):

"Application scope" mean normal java object and classes. Use static fields, singletons, e.t.c